# Android Camera2 Manual Settings

Tags: java, android, android-camera2

I am using a Nexus 6P and it looks like when I switch into manual camera 2 mode: setting the focus, sensor sensitivity, as well as the sensor exposure time to valid values; my auto white balance gets turned off. However this is not the case on my Note 5. I can't see to figure out why !

Answer (score 1):

It is normal, when you switch your `captureRequest` to `MANUAL_TEMPLATE` all your modes are switched to Off. As documentation says:

> A basic template for direct application control of capture parameters. All automatic control is disabled (auto-exposure, auto-white balance, auto-focus), and post-processing parameters are set to preview quality. The manual capture parameters (exposure, sensitivity, and so on) are set to reasonable defaults, but should be overriden by the application depending on the intended use case. This template is guaranteed to be supported on camera devices that support the MANUAL_SENSOR capability.

In your case, I suggest you to user a `TEMPLATE_PREVIEW` template until the user or you modify one value, then you can switch to a `MANUAL_TEMPLATE` and together with the setted value, put a default values to your builder to avoid a black preview without parameters.